# Proof: If a real-value function is continuous in a closed bounded interval, then the function is bounded

Tags: calculus, continuity

I am reading about the theorems for continuous functions. The following theorems/axioms are proven in the book and is assumed going forward:

Axiom: Every growing and bounded sequence of real numbers has a limit.

(I)

Let $I_k=[a_k,b_k]$, $k=1,2,...,$ be a sequence of intervalls on the real axis that are contracting in the sense that $I_1\supseteq I_2\supseteq I_3\supseteq...$.

Then both the sequence $(a_k)^\infty _{k=1}$ of leftward points and $(b_k)^\infty _{k=1}$ of rightward points have a limit when $k\rightarrow\infty$. If also the length $b_k-a_k\rightarrow 0$ when $k\rightarrow \infty$, then the two limits are equal.

(II)

If a real-value function $f$ is continuous in the closed interval $a\leq x\leq b$ and $f(a)\neq f(b)$, then $f$ assumes every value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$

(III)

If the function $f$ is continuous in the closed bounded intervall [a,b], then $f$ is bounded in [a,b]

My problem

Theorem 4:
If the real-value function $f$ is continuous in the closed bounded intervall [a,b], then $f$ has a maximum and minimum value

Proof: According to (III), $f$'s values are within a bounded intervall [A,B]. Let $C_1$ be the midpoint of this intervall. If $f(x)\leq C_1$ for all $x$ in [a,b] we will choose the intervall $[A,C_1]$. Otherwise there exists a point $x$ in [a,b] for which $f(x)>C_1$, in that case we will choose the intervall $[C_1,B]$. We call the chosen intervall $I_1=[A_1,B_1]$. It has the properties:

$f(x)\leq B_1$ for all $x\in [a,b]$

and

$f(x_1)\geq A_1$ for some $x_1\in [a,b]$

If we repeat this process with successive halving the intervall, then we get a sequence of contracting intervalls $I_k=[A_k,B_k]$ (i.e. $I_1\supseteq I_2 \supseteq I_3 ...$) and points $x_k\in [a,b]$ so that

(1) $f(x)\leq B_k$ for all $x\in [a,b]$

and

(2) $f(x_k)\geq A_k$.

From (I) follows that the sequences of $(A_k)^\infty _{k=1}$ and $(B_k)^\infty _{k=1}$ have a shared limit $M$ when $k\rightarrow \infty$. From (1) we now get

(3) $f(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in [a,b]$

Further from (2) it follows that

(4) $f(x_k)\rightarrow M$ when $k\rightarrow \infty$

Here is where my problem lies. This to me seems to be sufficient to prove the theorem since the function is assumed to be continuous which means that the value of $f(x_k)$ would, by the definition of continuous, equal its limit. However the book goes on to now prove that $f(x_k)=M$ when $k\rightarrow \infty$. It does this by assuming that $f(x)<M$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, which means that the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{M-f(x)},a\le x\le b$ is continuous. But this causes a contradiction.

Why is this last step needed?

Comment: The continuous image of a compact set is compact. A ssubset of $\mathbb R^n$, in particular, a subset of $\mathbb R$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded. Of course, we're taking the usual topology of $\mathbb R$. The continous image of a connected set is connected. The only connected subsets of $\mathbb R$ are the various kinds of intervals & also the singleton sets. Thus the continous image of $[a,b]$ has the form $\{\gamma \}$ or $[\alpha,\beta]$ where $\alpha < \beta$,i.e. a continuous function on a closed bounded interval is constant or has a min, a max& all values in bet ween.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof only needs to be slightly modified. This is an interesting proof

So now your goal is to prove that $\max_{a\leq x\leq b}f(x)$ exists (namely it would be impossible that $\{f(x)|a\leq x\leq b\}=(0,1)$, for instance). Step 1 to 4 has constructed an $M$, and we need to show that $M$ the maxium value we desired. We have already shown that $M\geq f(x)$, $x\in[a,b]$. What remained to be done is to show that $M>f(x)$ can not strictly hold for every $x\in [a,b]$. This can be shown by the B-W theorem. $\{x_n\}$ has a sub-sequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow+\infty} x_{n_k}=c$ exists. Then $f(c)=M$, which implies $M=\max f$ exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What confuses me is why (3) and (4) combined with the function being continuous isn't sufficient to prove $f(x_k)=M$ is the maximum. Doesn't the fact that $f$ is continuous and $f(x_k)\rightarrow M$ imply that $M>f(x)$ can not strictly hold fore every $x\in [a,b]$?

Comment: So why $M>f(x)$ can not always strictly hold? You need to construct an $x_0$ subject to $f(x_0)=M$, and this construction requires the B-W theorem, as is explained in my answer. If you think that I did not understand your proof, you can add more detail.